# How change image in generated imagebox vb

Tags: vb.net

I have to do a program where I can generate Button, Label, ImageBox and work with them. Now I am searching how change image in created ImageBox, it writes: this element doesn't exist. How can I get access to the created elements?

```
 Dim PictureB As New PictureBox
 PictureB.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 120)
 PictureB.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(350, 20)
 PictureB.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
 TabPage1.Controls.Add(PictureB)

 "New sub"
 OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
 PictureB.ImageLocation = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
```

Comment: `PictureB` does not exist in your new sub, but it does exist in `TabPage1.Controls`. You should loop through `TabPage1.Controls` until you find the picturebox you want, and then set the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PictureB` is not accessible in your "new sub" because it only exists in the subprocedure that you created it in as a *temporary, private* variable. The PictureBox, however, that you created, does exist in `TabPage1.Controls`, so you can access it in a loop.

Based on your requirements, it seems that you also need to get the exact PictureBox that you created, so I would suggest adding a Name to it when you create it, something like `PictureB.Name = "Pic1"`. I have included a sample Sub below that shows how you might accomplish your goal.

```
Public Sub SetImage(ByVal PictureBoxName As String)
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each c As Control In TabPage1.Controls
            Dim pb As PictureBox = TryCast(c, PictureBox)
            If Not IsNothing(pb) Then
                If pb.Name = PictureBoxName Then
                    pb.ImageLocation = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could look into creating event handles instead: that would be more involved, but would be a good learning experience.